# Unavailable Camera control API functions, Sony Development SDK, Camera WX500

Tags: camera, sony

I am trying to modify the CameraRemoteSampleApp provided by the Sony SDK to add full control over the aperture, iso, and shutter speed to the interface.

At this point however all the relevant functions are off limits.
The documentation defines these functions as "available if the latest version of the PlayMemories Smart Remote Control is installed and in use".

a) The smart remote control is installed and running, with the smartphone connected through it and wifi (Samsung Galaxy SIII).

b) I can take photos with the SDK Sample App.

c) Using the available API list shows that the functions exist but are not available.

d) Calling one of those functions directly returns "Not Available Now". This error code is not present in the documentation.

How can one get access to ISO/F-number/Shutter speed functions in this case?

```
JSON requests and responses:
Request Methods:  {"id":1,"method":"getMethodTypes","version":"1.0","params":[""]}
Response: {"id":1,"results":[["actTakePicture",[],["string*"],"1.0"],["actZoom",["string","string"],["int"],"1.0"],["awaitTakePicture",[],["string*"],"1.0"],["cancelTouchAFPosition",[],[],"1.0"],["getApplicationInfo",[],["string","string"],"1.0"],["getAvailableApiList",[],["string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableExposureCompensation",[],["int","int","int","int"],"1.0"],["getAvailableExposureMode",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableFNumber",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableFlashMode",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableFocusMode",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableIsoSpeedRate",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableLiveviewSize",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailablePostviewImageSize",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableSelfTimer",[],["int","int*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableShootMode",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableShutterSpeed",[],["string","string*"],"1.0"],["getAvailableWhiteBalance",[],["{\"whiteBalanceMode\":\"string\", \"colorTemperature\":\"int\"}","{\"whiteBalanceMode\":\"string\", \"colorTemperatureRange\":\"int*\"}*"],"1.0"],["getEvent",["bool"],["{\"type\":\"string\", \"names\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"cameraStatus\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"zoomPosition\":\"int\", \"zoomNumberBox\":\"int\", \"zoomIndexCurrentBox\":\"int\", \"zoomPositionCurrentBox\":\"int\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"liveviewStatus\":\"bool\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"liveviewOrientation\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"takePictureUrl\":\"string*\"}*","{\"type\":\"string\", \"continuousError\":\"string\", \"isContinued\":\"bool\"}*","{\"type\":\"string\", \"triggeredError\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"sceneRecognition\":\"string\", \"steadyRecognition\":\"string\", \"motionRecognition\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"formatResult\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"storageID\":\"string\", \"recordTarget\":\"bool\", \"numberOfRecordableImages\":\"int\", \"recordableTime\":\"int\", \"storageDescription\":\"string\"}*","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentBeepMode\":\"string\", \"beepModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentCameraFunction\":\"string\", \"cameraFunctionCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentMovieQuality\":\"string\", \"movieQualityCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"checkAvailability\":\"bool\", \"currentAspect\":\"string\", \"currentSize\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"cameraFunctionResult\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentSteadyMode\":\"string\", \"steadyModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentViewAngle\":\"int\", \"viewAngleCandidates\":\"int*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentExposureMode\":\"string\", \"exposureModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentPostviewImageSize\":\"string\", \"postviewImageSizeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentSelfTimer\":\"int\", \"selfTimerCandidates\":\"int*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentShootMode\":\"string\", \"shootModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentAELock\":\"bool\", \"aeLockCandidates\":\"bool*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"checkAvailability\":\"bool\", \"currentBracketShootMode\":\"string\", \"currentBracketShootModeOption\":\"string\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"checkAvailability\":\"bool\", \"currentCreativeStyle\":\"string\", \"currentCreativeStyleContrast\":\"int\", \"currentCreativeStyleSaturation\":\"int\", \"currentCreativeStyleSharpness\":\"int\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentExposureCompensation\":\"int\", \"maxExposureCompensation\":\"int\", \"minExposureCompensation\":\"int\", \"stepIndexOfExposureCompensation\":\"int\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentFlashMode\":\"string\", \"flashModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentFNumber\":\"string\", \"fNumberCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentFocusMode\":\"string\", \"focusModeCandidates\":\"string*\"}","{\"type\":\"string\", \"currentIsoSpeedRate\":\"str
Request Versions:  {"id":2,"method":"getVersions","version":"1.0","params":[]}
Response: {"id":2,"result":[["1.0"]]}
Request API:  {"id":3,"method":"getAvailableApiList","version":"1.0","params":[]}
Response: {"id":3,"result":[["getVersions","getMethodTypes","getApplicationInfo","getAvailableApiList","getEvent","actTakePicture","stopRecMode","startLiveview","stopLiveview","actZoom","setSelfTimer","getSelfTimer","getAvailableSelfTimer","getSupportedSelfTimer","setExposureCompensation","getExposureCompensation","getAvailableExposureCompensation","getSupportedExposureCompensation","setShootMode","getShootMode","getAvailableShootMode","getSupportedShootMode","getSupportedFlashMode"]]}


Request Flash:  {"id":5,"method":"getSupportedFlashMode","version":"1.0","params":[]}
Response Flash: {"id":5,"result":[["off","auto","on","slowSync","rearSync"]]}
Request speed:  {"id":5,"method":"getAvailableShutterSpeed","version":"1.0","params":[]}
Response speed: {"id":5,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things that you can check first:

1. Do you have the latest version of Smart Remote Control installed?
2. Do you have the latest firmware update for your camera?

Comment: I have updated the remote control app from 4.00 to 4.10. The results:

More options in the Play memories Smartphone app.

Even fewer available APIs using the SDK.


As of today, there are no firmware updates available on the Sony website for the DSC WX500

Comment: The (new) latest update (4.30) has fixed the problem.